# Error by converting qcow2 to vdi with qemu-img

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, vdi

I'm trying to convert .qcow2  to .vdi on my Ubuntu VM with a command 
`qemu-img convert -f qcow2 qcow2_file_name.qcow2 -O vdi vdi_file_name.vdi`

But I'm getting the following message:
`qemu-img: Could not open 'qcow2_file_name.qcow2': No such file or directory`

The file is in a Downloads folder, and I tried to move it to Home, but it didn't help.
Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command must be like this: 
`qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vdi file.qcow2 file.vdi`